# Convolutional Autoencoder only learning on 1 channel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

My data is of shape (100, 2, 2) and my code is learning on channel [:, :, 0], but not on channel [:, :, 1]

The relevant portion of my code is

Setup

```
self.encoder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, input_shape, name='x')
self.regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=0.1)
```

Encoder:

```
with tf.variable_scope("encoder"):
   conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(self.encoder_input, filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 2),
   activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer)
   mp1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, pool_size=(4, 1), strides=(4, 1))
   conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(mp1, filters=64, kernel_size=(2, 2),
   activation=None, padding='same', kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer)
   return conv2
```

where conv2 is then fed into the Decoder:

```
def _construct_decoder(self, encoded):
   with tf.variable_scope("decoder"):
   upsample1 = tf.image.resize_images(encoded, size=(50, 2), method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
   conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=upsample1, filters=32, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same',
   activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer)
   upsample2 = tf.image.resize_images(conv4, size=(100, 2), method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
   conv5 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=upsample2, filters=2, kernel_size=(2, 2), padding='same',
   activation=None, kernel_regularizer=self.regularizer)
   self.decoder = conv5
```

My losses are as follows:

```
base_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=self.encoder_input, predictions=self.decoder)
reg_losses = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)
loss = tf.add_n([base_loss] + reg_losses, name="loss")

cost = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
tf.summary.scalar('cost', cost)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr)

grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
# Update the weights wrt to the gradient
optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads)
# Save the grads with tf.summary.histogram
for index, grad in enumerate(grads):
    tf.summary.histogram("{}-grad".format(grads[index][1].name), grads[index])
```

I know it's not learning on the second channel because I plot the max, min, s.dev and so forth for the difference between actual and predicted for each channel. I'm not really sure why it's learning on the first but not on the second - anyone have any ideas?